# How to compare dates in Mongo query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get the Mongo database to return all of the records created within the past week.
Each record has a field `'created at'` which will be something like `'6/22/17 09:14'`. How do I check if this date occurred in the past week?

I have some code that looks like this:

```
the_collection.find({ALERT_CREATED : {&gt : new Date() - ONE_WEEK}}).toArray(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    } else {
        callback(null, results);
    }
});
```

With the different date formats, the two dates can't be compared.

**UPDATE:**
To clarify the issue, the dates in the database have the form `6/22/17 09:14` and as such cannot be compared correctly against a Date() object. Is there any way to compare them correctly?

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: I would strongly suggest storing dates as Date type, so you can perform date comparisons with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date does not seem to be a standardized format. You would have to manually convert the given string into a valid date string.

One way is splitting up your string and using `dateFormParts` as documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) to construct a date.

```
{
    $dateFromParts : {
        'year': <year>, 'month': <month>, 'day': <day>,
        'hour': <hour>, 'minute': <minute>, 'second': <second>,
        'milliseconds': <ms>, 'timezone': <tzExpression>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to subtract days in MongoDB query. Please try below code:

```
   the_collection.find(
   {
       "ALERT_CREATED": 
       {
           $gte: (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
       }
   })

   1 day = 1*24*60*60000 = 1 x 24 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds x 1000 milliseconds
```

Comment: This is also in a different date format as specified. The dates will not compare correctly.

Answer (score 2):

First you need the date to compare the `created_at` field to (today - 7), in MongoDB's date format.  Then get only dates that come after.

```
var lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() -7);

db.the_collection.find({'created_at': {'$gte': lastWeek}});
```

Comment: This does not work. `6/22/17 15:44 > Thu Jun 15 2017 15:44:04 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)` returns false. Additionally, this does not fix the problem; the dates are still in different formats.